# Google App Engine Datastore Faceted Search

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Has any one implemented Faceted Search using Google App Engine Datastore?

Answer (score 1):

A built-in faceted search is now being alpha-tested on GAE, see https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=6695

Comment: As of early 2015, GAE's own faceted search is available to everyone in beta, see https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/faceted_search

Answer (score 0):

the [bigtablesearch](http://code.google.com/p/bigtablesearch/) project claims to support faceted search.

there are a number of other full text search projects for the app engine datastore, including
[gae-search](http://gae-full-text-search.appspot.com/),
[bill katz's](http://www.billkatz.com/2009/6/Simple-Full-Text-Search-for-App-Engine), and the venerable [ext.search](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/search/__init__.py). afaik none of them have faceted search though.